# What alphabetic labels in phone dialer mean?

Tags: android, iphone, android-layout, view

I am writing a phone dialer for my apps in both Android and iPhone.

I realize that there are alphabetic labels below (or beside) numeric labels of keypad buttons in dialer layout of many calling apps.

example:

```
below '1' is blank

below '2' is 'abc'

below '3' is 'def'

...
```

Can any body explain why this happens?

and what does 'abc', 'def',... means in this case?

**Updated:**

[image]

Comment: Generation Y Vs. Generation Z :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in numeric mode .. only numbers but if you are in other mode like text .. so you will use these characters i.e:
 '2' is 'abc'

press 1st time ==> a 
press 2nd time ==> b 
press 3rd time ==> c

hold press on that button ==> 2 (number)

this is the mechanism generally.

=================update ...

:) you added this image later .. I didnt note it . well this layout is special and for quick contact search(names and numbers) ..i.e. if you have contact Sam(+111111), so press 726 , that will bring him directly or similar names or numbers. So those characters are keys map to help user to assign correct input... hope that will explain what you want .

Comment: I think in text mode user may should use `virtual keyboard` instead if they want to make an sms or e-mail. But i see no config for text mode in keypad tab and reason why they input a text in outgoing call number.

Comment: :) you added this image later .. I didnt note it . well this layout is special and for quick contact search(names and numbers) ..i.e. if you have contact Sam(+111111), so press 726 , that will bring him directly or similar names or numbers. So those characters are keys map to help user to assign correct input... hope that will explain what you want ..

Comment: Thanks you, Mohammed. You are right about this. There are some apps is designed with alphabetic dialer but they do not support for mapping with phone book. It is reason why i had confused about it.

Comment: Your second comment is exactly what i need. Pls, update your answer.